# A* (A star algorithm) implementation in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

I am working on my project but now i am puzzled at A* algorithm implementation. I have successfully done these things. please see the attached image
https://s12.postimg.org/f3o1xtprx/Working.png
Anyone please guide me how to implement A* algorithm.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247137/a*-(a-star-algorithm)-implementation-in-gazebo/) by [xeeshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28330/xeeshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-11-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-11-03**:\

1. What is your question? This seems like asking for help on a homework.
2. Where is your actual problem in implementing it? Don't you understand the algorithm?
3. `Gazebo` is a simulator, you don't implement an algorithm for navigation in there
4. What are those images supposed to tell us?

**Comment by [xeeshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28330/xeeshan/) on 2016-11-03**:
Sorry for the confusion.
Actually, I have followed tutorial of pioneer robot model and successfully executed the simulation in Gazebo and RVIZ.
In the Image attached shows the current progress like in the image the red arrow that tells the robot to move in that direction.

**Comment by [xeeshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28330/xeeshan/) on 2016-11-03**:
But I need to set a point on the map and calculate the distance through A* algorithm. For this I need help that where I have to write A* code (in global planner or in local planner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [move_base package](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) will do that for you. By default it uses Dijkstra's algorithm which is very similar to  A-star, but you can change it to A-star if you like.

---

Originally posted by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) with karma: 545 on 2016-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0